# Start a Fragment from a Service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-service

My `Activity`hosts 3 tabs and each tab is a `Fragment`. 
I also have a `Service` which query a database perdiodically. Depending on the result of the query, I raise a `Notification` (from the `Service`).

When I click on the `Notification`, is it possible to launch a specific fragment? If yes, how can I do so?

Here is what I've done so far, in my `Service` class:

```
// When notification is clicked, go back to TabOperations Fragment
Intent i = new Intent(this, TabOperations.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,  i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); // Give the phone access to the app
notification.setContentIntent(pi);

// Issue notification
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(UNIQUE_ID, notification.build());
```

Of course, this does not work.

Any advice?

Comment: No you can't "launch a fragment". Fragments don't exist outside an activity. To solve your problem, launch the activity that has 3 tabs and pass in an intent parameter which tells the activity which tab should be navigated to. The activity then listens to this intent parameter and reacts to it. Of course, you have to code all of this yourself.

Comment: see PendingIntent docs on what android components can be notified by a Notification

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `Service` sending a `Notification`, perhaps you would be better off with a different messaging system. For example, you can utilize the Observer pattern (or third-party libraries like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)) to send a message from the Service to the Activity that cares about such events. The activity can then use the event to start and attach the Fragment as necessary.